# How to return float32 values from numpy.fft.rfft?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I'm dealing with `float32`, and I don't want to change it to `float64` when applying `numpy.fft.rfft`, so how can I do that? Or is there any similar function roughly as fast as numpy?

Comment: `rfft` uses compiled code, so the returned dtype is determined by how that was compiled.  I don't see anything in the Python level code that lets you control the return dtype.  But as usual can use `astype` to cast the result.

Comment: @hpaulj Do you think this might cause any data loss?

Comment: @catfour. If anything, I'd expect it to increase your accuracy, but at the cost of some space